# sympy symbolic simplify Norm CDF PDF?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, sympy, symbolic-math, normal-distribution

looking for a way to simply the following. Calculating a few derivatives involving a normal cdf.

When trying to simplify, I want them in terms of norm pdf [0,1] and norm cdf [0,1]. How do I get the symbolic answer in terms of norm cdf norm pdf without erf.

For example the delta calculation should simplify to Norm.cdf(d1) see image below;

[Delta Simp in Terms of CDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVTux.jpg)

For another example the theta function should simplify to a function in terms of norm pdf and cdf see imeage below.

[Theta Simp in Terms of CDF and PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv72A.jpg)

Enclosed code below, please advise on how to get the desired simplification.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.stats import Normal, cdf


#spot, strike, volatility, time, interest rate, time at expiry, d1, and d2
S, K, sigma, t, r, T, d1, d2 = sp.symbols('S_t,K,sigma,t,r,T,d_1,d_2')

#define a symbol to represent the normal CDF
N = sp.Function('N')

#Black and Scholes price
C = S * N(d1) - N(d2) * K * sp.exp(-r * (T-t))




#expanded d1 and d2 for substitution:
d1_sub = (sp.ln(S / K) + (r + sp.Rational(1,2) * sigma ** 2) * (T-t)) / (sigma * sp.sqrt(T-t))
d2_sub = d1 - sigma * sp.sqrt(T-t)

#instance a standard normal distribution:
Norm = Normal('N',0.0, 1.0)

#define the long form b-s equation with all substitutions:
bs = C.subs(N, cdf(Norm)).subs(d2, d2_sub).subs(d1, d1_sub)

#Callable function for black and scholes price:
#example usage: bs_calc(100, 98, 0.15, 0, 0.03, 0.5)
bs_calc = sp.lambdify((S, K, sigma, t, r, T), bs)


print("Delta -> Mess")
print(sp.diff(bs,S))

print('Delta -> mess unresolved')
print(sp.simplify(sp.diff(bs,S)))

print("Theta -> Even worse Mess")
print(sp.diff(bs,T))

print('Theta -> Even Worse unresolved')
print(sp.simplify(sp.diff(bs,T)))
```

The solution set prints this to console:

runfile('myfile')

Delta -> Mess
-0.5*sqrt(2)*K*exp(-r*(T - t))*exp(-0.5*(-sigma*sqrt(T - t) + ((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)))**2)/(sqrt(pi)*S_t*sigma*sqrt(T - t)) + erf(0.5*sqrt(2)*((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)))/2 + 1/2 + 0.5*sqrt(2)*exp(-0.5*((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))**2/(sigma**2*(T - t)))/(sqrt(pi)*sigma*sqrt(T - t))

Delta -> mess unresolved
-0.5*sqrt(2)*K*exp(-r*(T - t))*exp(-0.5*(sigma*sqrt(T - t) - ((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)))**2)/(sqrt(pi)*S_t*sigma*sqrt(T - t)) + erf(0.5*sqrt(2)*((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)))/2 + 1/2 + 0.5*sqrt(2)*exp(-0.5*((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))**2/(sigma**2*(T - t)))/(sqrt(pi)*sigma*sqrt(T - t))

Theta -> Even worse Mess
K*r*(erf(0.5*sqrt(2)*(-sigma*sqrt(T - t) + ((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t))))/2 + 1/2)*exp(-r*(T - t)) - 0.5*sqrt(2)*K*(-sigma/(2*sqrt(T - t)) + (r + sigma**2/2)/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)) - ((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(2*sigma*(T - t)**(3/2)))*exp(-r*(T - t))*exp(-0.5*(-sigma*sqrt(T - t) + ((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)))**2)/sqrt(pi) + S_t*(0.5*sqrt(2)*(r + sigma**2/2)/(sigma*sqrt(T - t)) - 0.25*sqrt(2)*((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))/(sigma*(T - t)**(3/2)))*exp(-0.5*((T - t)*(r + sigma**2/2) + log(S_t/K))**2/(sigma**2*(T - t)))/sqrt(pi)

Theta -> Even Worse unresolved
(-pi*K*r*sigma*(T - t)**(9/2)*(erf(sqrt(2)*(0.5*sigma**2*(T - t) - 0.25*(T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) - 0.5*log(S_t/K))/(sigma*sqrt(T - t))) - 1)*exp((r*sigma**2*(T - t)**2 + 0.125*((T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) + 2*log(S_t/K))**2 + 0.125*(2*sigma**2*(T - t) - (T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) - 2*log(S_t/K))**2)/(sigma**2*(T - t))) + 0.25*sqrt(2)*sqrt(pi)*K*(T - t)**3*(2*sigma**2*(T - t) - (T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) + 2*log(S_t/K))*exp((r*sigma**2*(T - t)**2 + 0.125*((T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) + 2*log(S_t/K))**2)/(sigma**2*(T - t))) + 2*sqrt(2)*sqrt(pi)*S_t*(T - t)**3*(0.125*(T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) - 0.25*log(S_t/K))*exp((2*r*sigma**2*(T - t)**2 + 0.125*(2*sigma**2*(T - t) - (T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) - 2*log(S_t/K))**2)/(sigma**2*(T - t))))*exp(-(2*r*sigma**2*(T - t)**2 + 0.125*((T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) + 2*log(S_t/K))**2 + 0.125*(2*sigma**2*(T - t) - (T - t)*(2*r + sigma**2) - 2*log(S_t/K))**2)/(sigma**2*(T - t)))/(2*pi*sigma*(T - t)**(9/2))

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using floats where possible so it's better to use `Normal('N', 0, 1)` as I did for the output below.

There isn't a Phi function in sympy for the cdf of a normal distribution because it is expressed in terms of erf instead. You can define your own Phi function though:

```
In [108]: phi = Function('phi')                                                                                                   

In [109]: class Phi(Function): 
     ...:     def _eval_derivative(self, x): 
     ...:         return phi(self.args[0]) * self.args[0].diff(x) 
     ...:                                                                                                                         

In [110]: bs.subs(erf, Lambda(x, 2*Phi(x*sqrt(2))-1))                                                                             
Out[110]: 
     ⎛                        ⎛     2⎞          ⎞                   ⎛        ⎛     2⎞          ⎞
     ⎜                        ⎜    σ ⎟      ⎛Sₜ⎞⎟                   ⎜        ⎜    σ ⎟      ⎛Sₜ⎞⎟
     ⎜                (T - t)⋅⎜r + ──⎟ + log⎜──⎟⎟                   ⎜(T - t)⋅⎜r + ──⎟ + log⎜──⎟⎟
     ⎜      _______           ⎝    2 ⎠      ⎝K ⎠⎟  -r⋅(T - t)       ⎜        ⎝    2 ⎠      ⎝K ⎠⎟
- K⋅Φ⎜- σ⋅╲╱ T - t  + ──────────────────────────⎟⋅ℯ           + Sₜ⋅Φ⎜──────────────────────────⎟
     ⎜                           _______        ⎟                   ⎜           _______        ⎟
     ⎝                       σ⋅╲╱ T - t         ⎠                   ⎝       σ⋅╲╱ T - t         ⎠

In [111]: bs.subs(erf, Lambda(x, 2*Phi(x*sqrt(2))-1)).diff(S)                                                                     
Out[111]: 
     ⎛                        ⎛     2⎞          ⎞                                                ⎛        ⎛     2⎞          ⎞
     ⎜                        ⎜    σ ⎟      ⎛Sₜ⎞⎟                                                ⎜        ⎜    σ ⎟      ⎛Sₜ⎞⎟
     ⎜                (T - t)⋅⎜r + ──⎟ + log⎜──⎟⎟                                                ⎜(T - t)⋅⎜r + ──⎟ + log⎜──⎟⎟
     ⎜      _______           ⎝    2 ⎠      ⎝K ⎠⎟  -r⋅(T - t)    ⎛        ⎛     2⎞          ⎞    ⎜        ⎝    2 ⎠      ⎝K ⎠⎟
  K⋅φ⎜- σ⋅╲╱ T - t  + ──────────────────────────⎟⋅ℯ              ⎜        ⎜    σ ⎟      ⎛Sₜ⎞⎟   φ⎜──────────────────────────⎟
     ⎜                           _______        ⎟                ⎜(T - t)⋅⎜r + ──⎟ + log⎜──⎟⎟    ⎜           _______        ⎟
     ⎝                       σ⋅╲╱ T - t         ⎠                ⎜        ⎝    2 ⎠      ⎝K ⎠⎟    ⎝       σ⋅╲╱ T - t         ⎠
- ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + Φ⎜──────────────────────────⎟ + ─────────────────────────────
                                _______                          ⎜           _______        ⎟                _______         
                         Sₜ⋅σ⋅╲╱ T - t                           ⎝       σ⋅╲╱ T - t         ⎠            σ⋅╲╱ T - t
```